# How to make VBS give itself permissions and dont ask user in future?

Tags: vbscript

I made vbs virus for my friend but i never knew how to make it have permission rights. For example programs after their installation dont ask user to permission for something. It just have permissions. How do i do the same with my vbs?

Comment: **Welcome to SO!** I'm still choking after you said _i made a vbs virus for my friend_, but could you elaborate? **Are you trying to give your VBS permissions, or a VBS _Virus_ permissions?**

Comment: I mean doing it will not ask user "Are you really sure to start this program" about launching after boot, or denying acess to some folders.. I want to give my virus full control so it can edit registry etc.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
After reading this you might consider deleting your question. I decided, after reading it myself, to flag your question.

Comment: Is this still active? @Azari

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a task that will run the .vbs file at system startup. Search for it in Windows "Task Planning" and create a new task. It is important here that you tick the "Run as admin" checkbox. You also have to enter the file path and choose when it should start.

Good Luck

Jonas